# How to find the index of the max value of pandas data array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max

With a dataFrame parsed into pandas.
The user can get the index (column) name of maximum value using `DataFrame.idxmax`
However, if all the values in the row are zero (or of **equal value**), then the index returns the first column by default.

Therefore, how can one filter for **all zero's** or all equal values so that no column name is returned.

I am using `pandas.DataFrame.idxmax` help files.
However, there is no filter option.

I believe that one can filter in pandas using a `loc[df['something']==value]`, but i am not sure how to do this for the max value.

```
import pandas as pd
myArr = {'column0':[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
    'column1':[1, 2, 0, 4, 5], 
    'column2':[100,200,0,400,500], 
    'column3':[1000,2000,0,4000,5000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myArr)
#print(df)

m = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print(m)
```

actual result:

```
0    column3
1    column3
2    column0
3    column3
4    column3
```

The value in the second row defaults to the first column because the values are zero (**or equal**).

How can this be filtered out ?

Comment: are you looking for `df.mask(df.eq(0).all(1)).idxmax(1)`? or may be `df.mask(df.nunique(1).eq(1)).idxmax(1)` ??

Comment: Is it a problem that **all** values are equal, or would it be equally problematic if there were at least 2 columns that shared the max?

Comment: i will try `df.mask(df.eq(0).all(1)).idxmax(1)` and see.

Comment: it is equally a problem that all values are equal. **Certainly a problem if all values are equal and zero**. Not a problem if there are two equal values (as one of those would be selected).  I have posted an acceptable answer below, but others may be able to post more concise answers...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer buy adding the below:

[1] filter for zero values first.
[2] next, find the maximums.

```
# apply a filter for rows with zero's
print('apply zero filter:')
nz = df.loc[df['column0'] > 0]
print(nz)

# find the max values of the rest
print('get max values:')
m = nz.idxmax(axis=1)
print(m)
```

The filtered columns are:

```
   column0  column1  column2  column3
0        1        1      100     1000
1        1        2      200     2000
3        1        4      400     4000
4        1        5      500     5000
```

The max column headings are:

```
0    column3
1    column3
3    column3
4    column3
```

Comment: It does not match if all the values of one row are equal and different from zeros.

Comment: correct,  this is because of the greater than sign `nz = df.loc[df['column0'] > 0]`.  The question was primarily for **zero**.  Please suggest alternative instead of a down vote (which is unproductive).

Comment: I didn't see that the answer was from you the OP, that's why I downvote and add a comment. I post an answer with some code detecting rows with equal values different from zero.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting same values different from zeros, the code below should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

myArr = {
    'column0': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 5],
    'column1': [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 5],
    'column2': [100, 200, 0, 400, 500, 5],
    'column3': [1000, 2000, 0, 4000, 5000, 5],
}
m = (
    pd.DataFrame(myArr)
    .assign(
        values_number=lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: len(pd.unique(s)), axis='columns')
    )
    .loc[lambda x: x['values_number'] > 1]
    .drop(['values_number'], axis='columns')
    .idxmax(axis=1)
)
print (m)
```

The lambda function associated to `values_number` count the number of unique values in the given row.

I also created a last row with the same values but different of zero.